# Call file upload API from Micronaut

Tags: okhttp, micronaut, micronaut-client

I need to call an API and upload file Bytes Data with Micronaut

It is similar what we use do to with OkHTTP like :

```
Response uploadResult = okHttpClient.newCall(new Request.Builder()
                .url(uploadUrl)
                .post(RequestBody.create(byteData))
                .build()
        ).execute();
```

I Have tried calling API using micronaut HTTP client add passing MUltipart Form Data

```
MultipartBody requestBody = MultipartBody.builder().addPart("data", uploadFile.getFilename(), fileContentBytes).build();
        httpClient = HttpClient.create(new URL(uploadUrl.getUpload_url()));
        HttpRequest<?> uploadRequest = HttpRequest.POST(uploadUrl.getUpload_url(), requestBody)
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE)
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, v2Request.getToken());
        Publisher<?> uploadResponse = httpClient.exchange(uploadRequest, HttpResponse.class);
```

I am just not sure how to find the event when upload has finished and proceed further !

---

I have tried subscribing the Publisher using Flux as follow

```
 HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(new URL(url));
            HttpRequest<FbPagePostRequest> request = HttpRequest.POST(url, postRequest).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token);
            Publisher<HttpResponse<FbPagePostResponse>> response = httpClient.exchange(request, FbPagePostResponse.class);
            Flux.from(response).map(data -> {
                if (data.status() != HttpStatus.OK || data.getBody().isEmpty()) {
                    log.error("Response of facebook page post " + response);
                    throw new PublicationException("Error posting on Facebook on Page : " + pageName);
                }
                return data.getBody().get();
            }).subscribe(returnObj::set);
```

But when I run this I get and error

```
Response of facebook page post FluxLift
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `subscribe` to the returned `Publisher` as described [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_simple_ways_to_create_a_flux_or_mono_and_subscribe_to_it)

```
subscribe(); // (1)

subscribe(Consumer<? super T> consumer);  // (2)

subscribe(Consumer<? super T> consumer,
          Consumer<? super Throwable> errorConsumer); // (3)

subscribe(Consumer<? super T> consumer,
          Consumer<? super Throwable> errorConsumer,
          Runnable completeConsumer); // (4)

subscribe(Consumer<? super T> consumer,
          Consumer<? super Throwable> errorConsumer,
          Runnable completeConsumer,
          Consumer<? super Subscription> subscriptionConsumer); // (5)
```

> 1. Subscribe and trigger the sequence.
> 2. Do something with each produced value.
> 3. Deal with values but also react to an error.
> 4. Deal with values and errors but also run some code when the sequence successfully completes.
> 5. Deal with values and errors and successful completion but also do something with the Subscription produced by this subscribe call.